# How do I positioning a div based upon percentages with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, positioning

I'm looking for help with positioning an object along X, and Y coordinates based upon percentage in order to allow it to move on top of everything when you scroll around the page.  The numbers are working, but the CSS seems to be confused, so all I need is alignment help.

Currently I have:

```
document.getElementById('block').style.display="style='position: absolute; left: place%; top: place%; transform: translate(place%, place%);'";
```

Example: office applications moving tool bars around when they snap off the toolbar holder, and sit there

The fiddle is: http://jsfiddle.net/JFqus/

Comment: try `position:static;` instead of absolute

Comment: Please create this in a jsFiddle. This one line of javascript isn't really very helpful so far. You are just applying CSS with the javascript, so try to get it going with just good ol CSS first.

Comment: The `display` style property accepts a value from a limited set of possible values (`block`, `inline`, etc.). What you've written isn't syntactically correct... not even close, I mean. Where did you take take from?

Comment: Side note: I assumed you mean `translate(-50%, -50%)` as this puts the element in the exact center regardless of its dimensions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to set multiple values in one line, this isn't possible.

```
document.getElementById('block').style.position = "absolute";
document.getElementById('block').style.left = document.getElementById('block').style.top = "50%";
document.getElementById('block').style.transform = "translate(50%, 50%)";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JFqus/2/

If you just want the styles to be applied all the time, you can add it right into the div's style attribute:

```
<div id="block" style="background-color:#000000;height:100px;width:100px;position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; transform: translate(50%, 50%);"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZazmC/

But this is ugly, you should separate styles from markup:

```
#block {
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%; top: 50%;
    transform: translate(50%, 50%);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZazmC/1/

Also, I think you want `position: fixed`, not `absolute`.

Comment: I'd separate it if I could do the CSS organically.

Answer (score 0):

use `element.style.cssText`, for example:

```
document.getElementById('block').style.cssText = 'position: absolute; /* ... */';
```

works in all browsers you likely care about: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_css.html#t30